# Can an implementation specify undefined behavior

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c11

> 3.4.1
>   
> 1 implementation-defined behavior
>   unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made

Can an implementation specify that, implementation-defined behavior is undefined behavior in cases where undefined behavior is a possible outcome?

For example:

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; *either the
>   result is implementation-defined* or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So as long as it is documented, can this result be undefined by the implementation and cause undefined behavior, or it *must* have a defined result for that implementaion?

Comment: Based on the rationale's statement *As with unspecified behavior, simply failing to translate the source containing the implementation-defined behavior is not an adequate response.*, I'd conclude that *IB* behaviour can't be *UB*. Generally, *failing to translate* is considered good than *undefined behaviour* in error/exceptional conditions. If standard states that even *failing to translate* is not adequate for IB then certainly leaving it as *undefined* is unacceptable. So, the answer is no, an implementation can't leave X is *undefined* if standard says X is *implementation defined*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, semantically this is not possible. Undefined behavior is what the term states, behavior that is not defined by the standard. If the standard requests implementation defined behavior, it explicitly request the implementation to specify what it does when a certain error occurs.

> **undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
>   of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
>   requirements

So an implementation could say *"under that and that circumstances this implementation raises a blurb signal"* but it can't say *"under that and that circumstances we don't tell you what we are doing"*.

Don't mystify undefined behavior as something that will happen or even as something that can be defined.

Comment: Out of all the answers you are the only one pointing out the problem.

Comment: @reader: The real problem is that the standard applies a level of specificity to the behavior of small signed values which would impede a relatively useful and non-surprising optimization (promote a register-stored variable of a signed type smaller than `int` with an `int`) while failing to specify a level of specificity sufficient to make unsigned values behave as an algebraic ring under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Very well written answer

Answer (score 2):

You can find a more detailed explanation of what "implementation defined" is intended to mean in the *C Rationale* - not a standard document *per se*, but a good reference.

In chapter 1.6 [*Definition of terms*](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/a.html#1-6):

> *Implementation-defined behavior* gives an implementor the freedom to choose the appropriate approach, but requires that this choice be explained to the user.  Behaviors designated as implementation-defined are generally those in which a user could make meaningful coding decisions based on the implementation definition.  Implementors should bear in mind this criterion when deciding how extensive an implementation definition ought to be.  As with unspecified behavior, simply failing to translate the source containing the implementation-defined behavior is not an adequate response.

You can't make a "reasonable coding decision" based on undefined behavior.

The C FAQ (again, not a standard, but a well-know reference) is [quite clear too](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html):

> **implementation-defined:** The implementation must pick some behavior; it may not fail to compile the program. (**The program using the construct is not incorrect.**) The choice must be documented. The Standard may specify a set of allowable behaviors from which to choose, or it may impose no particular requirements

Neither unspecified and implementation-defined behaviors are errors - compiler can't fail the translation. They are meant to give the implementation options to produce optimal code for the targeted environment.

Comment: Even though the C language imposes no requirements on what should happen when relational operators are given unrelated pointers, compilers for machines which could conveniently define a ranking among all pointers (including, but not limited to, those with linear memory architectures), have defined their relational operators to do so, and it was considered perfectly legitimate for code targeting such machines to take advantage of this, especially since C has never defined any portable alternative (while `(intptr_t)p < (intptr_t)q` will always yield 0 or 1, the standard says nothing...

Comment: ...about whether it will yield a meaningful ranking; indeed, I don't think the standard would even require that `(intptr_t)p == (intptr_t)p`, provided that `(void*)(intptr_t)p == (void*)p`).  I think it's very sad that while compilers have historically tended toward implementing a common superset of C, today's compiler writers seek to throw that all away and say that even behaviors which all modern hardware could support cleanly and efficiently must be replaced by clunky alternatives which don't express what code is actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of integers to smaller types is something of an oddball, since the standard clearly recognizes that some implementations may trap, but--uniquely--it requires that the trapping abide by the rules of signals; the decision to impose that requirement here but not elsewhere is somewhat curious, since in many cases it would impede what would otherwise be a straightforward optimization--replacing a signed integer variable whose type shorter than `int`, and whose address is never taken, with an `int`.

Nonetheless, for whatever reasons, the authors of the standard have gone out of their way to forbid that optimization.  [Note: If I were in charge of the standard, I would specify that an explicit *cast* to a shorter integer type would yield a value which when cast to an unsigned type of the same size would yield the same result as casting the value directly whenever such a value exists, but that a store of an oversized value directly to an lvalue *without a cast* would not be thus constrained; I didn't write the standard, though].

It's ironic, actually: given:

```
uint64t signedpow(int32_t n, uint32_t p) {
  uint64_t result;
  while(p--) { n*=n; result+=n; }
  return result;
}
uint64t unsignedpow(uint32_t n, uint32_t p) {
  uint64_t result;
  while(p--) { n*=n; result+=n; }
  return result;
}
```

On a platform where `int` is 32 bits, the latter would have defined semantics for all values of `n` and `p`, while the former would not, but on a platform where `int` is 64 bits, the reverse would be true.  A compiler for a typical 64-bit platform which didn't want to waste code on some other defined behavior would be required by the standard to mask off and sign-extended the signed `n` after each multiplication, but with some unsigned values the compiler could do anything it wanted, including going back in time and pretending that no implementation would ever promise to always perform half-sized unsigned multiplies in a fashion consistent with modular arithmetic.

Comment: If `int` == 64 bit, then in the second example, the result of `n*n` which types are after conversion: `int*int`, can always fit into an `int`. The result is then cast back to `uint32_t`, thus no undefined behavior can occur.

Comment: @reader: If `int`==64 bit, then squaring an `unsigned` which is 3037000500 or larger will yield an value greater than 9223372037000250000, and too large to fit in `int` which would only go up to 9223372036854775808; it's entirely plausible that if `unsignedpow` were called with a constnat value for `n` some compilers would recognize that Undefined Behavior would occur for values of `p` over a certain size and yield code which would not work for values beyond that.  A silly hole in the spec which really should be fixed, since it doesn't enable any useful optimizations but instead...

Comment: ...merely gives compilers an excuse to break code which would have worked 100% reliably on 99% of the compilers produced between 1980 and 2010.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Int could overflow.

Comment: @reader: Thus my point about irony: even though `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are supposed to be more "portable" than types like `int`, their behavior changes fundamentally depending upon the size of `int`.  I wish the C Standards Committee would define some new integral types for C whose behavior was essentially int-size independent: non-promotable "wrapping" types which would behave much as unsigned types do in contexts not involving promotion, and "number" types where overflows were allowed to arbitrarily retain precision, silently drop precision, or trigger implementation-defined...

Comment: ...traps when dropping precision, and where silent dropping of precision was not required to be consistent or permanent (e.g. after `num16 i=32767; i++;` it would be legal for `num32 j=i,k=i,l=i;` to arbitrarily load j, k, and l with any combination of 32768 and -32768. Such rules would allow compilers to pretend that "number" types of any size--not just those larger than `int`--will obey the rules of arithmetic, but if compile-time constants which aren't forced to particular types were required to be processed in a fashion consistent with the longest number type, then...

Comment: ...compilers for 64-bit machines wouldn't have to constrain math to 32-bit values in cases where code doesn't really care about it, but code which needs wrapping semantics wouldn't need to worry about unwanted numeric promotions.  Unfortunately, the rules of such types wouldn't allow as many phony "optimization" opportunities as those of the present ones.

Comment: I agree that integers should be fixed. And you solution of a new type might be the only one that could actually happen, since ordinary integer promotions are so ingrained in C that they could not be changed.

Comment: @reader: The approach I'd most like to see would be to add a new bitfield syntax where e.g. `struct foo { unsigned short a; unsigned char b; int x : { 12:a.2, 4:b:1}; };` would cause bits 0-3 of `x` to be mapped to bits 1-4 of `b` [4 bits starting at bit 1], and bits 4-15 of `x` to be mapped to bits 2-13 of `a` [12 bits starting at bit 2].  Anything that could be expressed with today's bitfields could be expressed portably using such a scheme, but the scheme would be portable.  Allowing a single value to combine multiple bitfields would lead to clunky code *except in cases where...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77823/discussion-between-supercat-and-reader).

Comment: @reader: I accidentally hit the "chat" button but finished my post in the chat thing.  Put `@supercat` before any reply in the chat if you want me to see it.

Answer (score 0):

As per `C11` standard, chapter 3.4.1,

> #### implementation-defined behavior
>
> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made

So, each implementation has to make a choice. Otherwise, it won't be *conforming*. Thus, we can say, it **must** have a defined result for that implementaion. That can be either of the below

- a *defined*  behavior, specific to that implementation, which will be exercised if the instruction is encountered.
- a *defined* signal which will be raied if the instrcution is encountered. (Mostly, saying that cannot be handled.)

**Related:**

1. From `C99` [Rationale Document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), Chapter 3, (*emphasis mine*)

> Implementation-defined behavior gives an implementor the freedom to choose the appropriate approach, but requires that this choice be explained to the user. Behaviors designated as implementation-defined are generally those in which a ***user could make meaningful coding decisions based on the implementation’s definition***. Implementors should bear in mind this criterion when deciding how extensive an implementation definition ought to be. As with unspecified behavior, simply failing to translate the source containing the  implementation defined behavior is not an adequate response.

Now, nobody can take "meaningful coding decisions" based on undefined behavior.

2. From [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html), Question 11.33,

> *implementation-defined:* The implementation must pick some behavior; it may not fail to compile the program. (The program using the construct is not incorrect.) The choice must be documented. The Standard may specify a set of allowable behaviors from which to choose, or it may impose no particular requirements.

The first sentence contains **must**, same as I mentioned before in my answer.

Comment: *it must have a defined result* You invented that. It nowhere says it must be defined. A *choice* can be made to have undefined behavior as long as it is documented.

Comment: @reader well, I think that is why the last option, raising the signal, is there.

Comment: Your last argument is countering your own conclusion.

Comment: well, +1 from me as this is also my opinion. don't know why so many downvotes.

Comment: @Zaibis don't know, maybe the choice of words are not expressive enough. I'm not very good in English vocabulary, so can't clarify much. I've tried to add required references and quotes to support my version.

Comment: @reader Please see the updates. HOpe that clarifies the issue I which was not able to explain properly. :-)

Comment: *are `generally` those* And that is rationale not the standard.

Comment: @reader I know, that's not the standard, but that is a _commonly followed reference_. And I added that because _I did not invent that **must**_. :-)

Comment: @reader: Would the standard allow an Implementation-Defined operation to have side effects that manifest themselves before the operation is performed?  I don't think the definition of Implementation-Defined Behavior extends that far.